# zipfile.BadZipfile: File is not a zip file

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7, zip, ziparchive

Код:

```
import urllib
import zipfile
import os

destination = '000.zip'
url = 'http://url/000.zip'
urllib.urlretrieve(url, destination)

z = zipfile.ZipFile('000.zip','r')
z.extractall()
z.close()

os.remove('000.zip')
```

Получаю такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testt.py", line 9, in <module>
    z = zipfile.ZipFile('000.zip')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 770, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 811, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
zipfile.BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
```

Как это можно пофиксить?
[image: Информация]

Comment: Ну так может это на самом деле не zip-файл? Почему вы считаете, что он должен открываться?

Comment: Я создал .zip файл, закинул его к себе на хостинг. Я уверен что это zip файл.

Comment: Ну а после urlretrieve вы пробовали открыть свежескачанный файл вручную?

Comment: Да, архив открывается.

Comment: А чем открываете?

Comment: Открываю WinRar-ом.

Comment: А кликните там кнопку «Информация» и покажите нам информацию об этом архиве

Comment: Прикрепил скриншот.

Comment: Ну вот, там написано, что это не zip-архив, а rar-архив — вот поэтому и не работает

Comment: Странно, я думал если  из .rar поменять на .zip, то меняется тип. Вообщем да, я создал zip архив через winrar и все заработало, спасибо.

Comment: Имя файла не значит абсолютно ничего, это не более чем подсказка для винды, какой программой открывать файл. Если переименовать в `000.mp3`, он не заиграет музыку, а останется тем же rar-архивом :)